# JQuery change event for select not working

Tags: jquery-ui

I have tried all the options i found on the forum, but could not get it to work.
I even tried click event but that is also not getting called.

I wonder what is wrong with my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">`enter code here`
$('#test.role.list').change(function(){
    alert("here");
});
```

```
<div>
    <form:select id="test.role.list" path="name">
        <form:option value="none" label="none"/> 
        <form:option value="my none" label="none"/>
    </form:select>
</div>
```

Comment: Is JQuery not liking the dots?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I've never seen things like `form:select`. What's this? Also, why use test.role.list (dots) to set an ID?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/c9FaA/1/ does this help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a list of permissions which are keys from the messageresource properties file, so the same thing i am using as id as well.                                                                The reason it is not working is correct as mentioned by the Lee. It considers the dots as different properties of the element with id "test" which is first string before dot and the next string as probably class. So i used the onchange event as

```
var Ele = document.geteElementByID("test.role.list");                        
ele.onchange = function(){
    alert("here");
}
```

it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the problesms are with dots in id.

You can use it as below,

```
    $('#test\\.role\\.list').change(function(){
        alert("here");
    });
```